# How to find unique extra column name between two data.frames?

Tags: r

I have two almost identical data.frames, and I want to find the unique column name that is added to the `x.2` object.

```
> colnames(x.1)
     [1] "listPrice"                        "rent"                             "floor"                            "livingArea"                      
     [5] "rooms"                            "published"                        "constructionYear"                 "objectType"                      
     [9] "booliId"                          "soldDate"                         "soldPrice"                        "url"                             
    [13] "additionalArea"                   "isNewConstruction"                "location.namedAreas"              "location.address.streetAddress"  
    [17] "location.address.city"            "location.position.latitude"       "location.position.longitude"      "location.region.municipalityName"
    [21] "location.region.countyName"       "location.distance.ocean"          "source.name"                      "source.id"                       
    [25] "source.type"                      "source.url"                       "areaSize"                         "priceDiff"                       
    [29] "perc.priceDiff"                   "sqrmPrice"


> colnames(x.2)
 [1] "listPrice"                        "livingArea"                       "additionalArea"                   "plotArea"                        
 [5] "rooms"                            "published"                        "constructionYear"                 "objectType"                      
 [9] "booliId"                          "soldDate"                         "soldPrice"                        "url"                             
[13] "isNewConstruction"                "floor"                            "rent"                             "location.namedAreas"             
[17] "location.address.streetAddress"   "location.address.city"            "location.position.latitude"       "location.position.longitude"     
[21] "location.region.municipalityName" "location.region.countyName"       "location.distance.ocean"          "source.name"                     
[25] "source.id"                        "source.type"                      "source.url"                       "areaSize"                        
[29] "priceDiff"                        "perc.priceDiff"                   "sqrmPrice"
```

Comment: Try `setidff` i.e. `setdiff(colnames(x.2), colnames(x.1))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setdiff` to get the column names that are in 'x.2' and not in 'x.1'

```
 setdiff(colnames(x.2), colnames(x.1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
colnames(x.2)[!colnames(x.2) %in% colnames(x.1)]
```